# jar spams console after completing manifest

Tags: java, manifest

I have main class in my package, I have manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: PortalGraMax
\n - its a new line here :-)
```

**Why running it in with 'java -jar test.jar' gives spam and is not executed as it should?:**
http://i50.tinypic.com/j7446q.png

Comment: What spam? Your picture shows no output.

Comment: Sorry, theres PAUSE after executing jar from bat file and its the same.

Comment: There's still no indication of what you mean by spam. I'd interpreted that to mean that it dumps a load of garbage to the console. It's not clear where a batch file comes into this either. You *really* need to clarify the question.

Comment: Ok, how to export this to run it http://i45.tinypic.com/24fik1s.png from jar file? When I run it in Eclipse console it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Given the second screenshot, it looks like your class name is wrong in the manifest. It should be:

```
Main-Class: szymon.GraPortal.PortalGraMax
```

(Note that your package name violates Java naming conventions by including capital letters, but that's a different matter.)

I'd have expected you to get an error such as:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PortalGraMax
```

with your current manifest, mind you...